# Tree Store Not Loading

Tags: extjs4

I am new to sencha Extjs, trying to load tree data dynamically, but my tree is not loading

my store as follows:

```
root:{
    //field:'Total',
    expanded: true,
    trade:'Total',
    text:'Total',
    children:['childs']
},
proxy:{
    type:'direct',
    directFn:type.getTreeData,
    root:'trade'
}
```

and my json response as follows:

```
[{"trade":"Market","childs":[
    {"childTrade":"bc","value":125.23},
    {"childTrade":"AndhraBank","value":14.25},
    {"childTrade":"ABC","value":78.36}]
},{"trade":"Electronincs","childs":[
    {"childTrade":"klo","value":125.23},
    {"childTrade":"bank","value":14.25},
    {"childTrade":"KBC","value":78.36}]
}]
```

Comment: Which version of ExtJS do you use?

Comment: Sencha ExtJS 4.2 @Darin Kolev